# getting error when install python-rtmplib

Tags: python-3.4

environment：

- python3.4.1
- cffi 1.1.2
- rtmp.lib
- vs2010
- win7 x64

when I install python-rtmplib by

pip install python-librtmp

or

pip install --use-wheel python-librtmp

i just got some link error

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python34\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python34\PCbuild\amd64 rtmp.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__librtmp build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\librtmp._librtmp.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\src/librtmp/amf.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\librtmp\_librtmp.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_librtmp.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\_librtmp.pyd.manifest`

`librtmp._librtmp.obj : warning LNK4197: 多次指定导出“PyInit__librtmp”；使用第一个规范`

`librtmp._librtmp.obj : error LNK2019: 无法解析的外部符号 RTMPPacket_Alloc，该符号在函数 _cffi_d_RTMPPacket_Alloc 中被引用`

`librtmp._librtmp.obj : error LNK2019: 无法解析的外部符号 RTMPPacket_Dump，该符号在函数 _cffi_d_RTMPPacket_Dump 中被引用`

why? What should I do?